# in my localhost crypt function not working php

Tags: php

WINDOWS-VISTA)

```
echo substr($pwd,0,2); --> executing fine
echo crypt($pwd,substr($pwd,0,2));--> WHILE EXECUTING System gets hang
```

But this snippet working fine in my live.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "gets hung"? Any error messages? Is your `error_reporting()` turned on?

Comment: its loading loading loading loading

Answer (score 3):

What version of PHP are you using?

This is a well-known bug on PHP, though it was fixed in 5.3.2RC3.

See these bug reports for more info:

- Fixed: [Bug #51167 crypt() hangs randomly when called with a salt](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51167)
- Assigned: [Bug #51424 crypt() function hangs after 3rd call](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51424)

You can use [hash_hmac()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) instead of `crypt()` for a quick fix.